# How to use Case Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Using C#.Net and MYSQL

I want to use a CASE Statement like SQL

Query

```
SELECT vehicleno, 
       brandname, 
       CASE 
         WHEN inexpire < 0 THEN 'Expired' 
         ELSE inexpire 
       END AS inexpire 
FROM   (SELECT Concat(plateno, vehicleno)   AS vehicleno, 
               brandname, 
               Datediff(inedate, Curdate()) AS inexpire 
        FROM   tb_car 
        WHERE  inedate < DATE_ADD(Curdate(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
        GROUP  BY vehicleno) AS tab1
```

When I run the Query it is showing the output as

`System.Byte[]` instead of "Expired"

In the above query inexpire is column values

How can I solve this issue.....

Need Query Help

Comment: You seem to mix the different data types for inexpire, either you get a numeric value (you do check if the value is less than 0) or the string 'Expired'.

Comment: What is `inexpire` meant to return? Do you want it to return the string 'Expired' if it has expired and the number of days cast to a string if it hasn't? Or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you would need to use the same datatype for both cases

e.g.

```
case when inexpire < 0 then 'Expired' else 'inexpired' end as inexpire
```

or

```
 case when inexpire < 0 then 1 else inexpire end as inexpire
```

**Edit**

Actually I just did a quick test on my machine this mixing of datatypes doesn't cause an error but the result just shows as `Blob` in MySQL Workbench

```
SELECT  
cast( CASE  WHEN inexpire < 0 THEN 'Expired' ELSE inexpire END as char) as inexpire
```

stops this issue as suggested [here](http://techrookies.blogspot.com/2008/07/when-databinding-results-in-systembyte.html). This should thus avoid the `Byte[]` issue

Comment: I'm actually surprised MySQL doesn't raise an error in this case. I think that Sybase, MS & IBM DB2/UDB all raise errors when the return type from a case differs (or at least there's no implicit conversion available). I'd be curious to know what the actual database type of `inexpired` is.

Comment: @Nathan - Maybe it does just cast the number to a string actually. I'm not in a position to test this at the moment.

Comment: MySQL's behaviour towards such expression can be configured. I think that by default it will issue a warning at most.

Comment: @Mhcl - I just did a quick test and it doesn't raise an error but shows up as `blob` in MySQL Workbench

Comment: inexpired is a table column values, no need to give in the single quotation, I tried your query when i use the else condition it is showing sytem.Byte error...., why it is coming, mysql why not taking the else statement

Answer (score 1):

`IF(inexpire < 0, 'Expired',inexpire) AS inexpire`